# Programmatically create meets for users in Google Groups

Tags: google-meet

I would ask you if it is possible to create a list of google meets for a group of user in google admin console or using API. In specific I need to create a meet link for each user in the group and the owner of the meeting should be each member of the group, so he/she can activate controls over meetings, like the join permission to join the meeting for users that not belong to the organization.

Thank you in advance for the help.